# How to model two relationships, and enforce that the pair is unique

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF model like so:

```
class Party(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

And two and only two parties can form an integration, which I currently have modeled like this:

```
class Integration(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    party_a = models.ForeignKey('Party')
    party_b = models.ForeignKey('Party')
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        unique_together = (('party_a', 'party_b'), ('party_b', 'party_a'))
```

The pair of `party_a` and `party_b` has to be unique; which party is which doesn't matter. So, Party 123 and Party 456 can only be integrated once. The `unique_together` doesn't help me out much here, so I setup a validator to do that.

```
class IntegrationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    party_a = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Party.objects.all())
    party_b = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Party.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Integration
    fields = ('id', 'party_a', 'party_b', 'enabled', 'active_date')

def validate(self, data):
    if len(Integration.objects.filter(party_a=data['party_a'], party_b=data['party_b'])) > 0 or \
                    len(Integration.objects.filter(party_a=data['party_b'], party_b=data['party_a'])) > 0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Integration already exists')
    return data
```

I'm wondering if this is the best way to model this relationship? My current solution seems to work okay, but as I test, I keep finding things I need to fix. Like I forgot the validator would trigger on a PUT.

Any suggestions are appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Compare party_a and party_b, put the little one in party_a, and the large one in party_b. This makes only one instance of the pair of parties exists in db. You can overwrite the save method of serializer to ensure this relation.

P.S. queryset.count seems more elegant than len(queryset), and here you could use queryset.exists instead.

Comment: I like the simplicity of that. I am a little worried someone in 5 years will be like "WTF is this?" but it is still pretty straightforward.